# Count words in column row by row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, function, procedure

I need build a query to extract the quantity of each row coluwn.
Example

Table Product
Column Description

```
+----+---------------------------------------------+
| Id | Description                                 |
+----+---------------------------------------------+
| 1  | Love test Love by Love                      |
| 2  | Value of Value is Value of Value the Value  |
+----+---------------------------------------------+
```

The result could be

```
+---+------+---------+
| 1 | Love | 3 times |
| 1 | test | 1 time  |
| 1 | by   | 1 time  |
+---+------+---------+

+---+-------+---------+
| 2 | Value | 5 times |
| 2 | of    | 2 times |
| 2 | is    | 1 times |
| 1 | the   | 1 times |
+---+-------+---------+
```

Comment: SQL is really a bad language for trying to do text processing like this.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in SQL?  SQL is not meant for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

This following script will return your desired result. The code taken from [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143472/split-a-column-at-every-whitespace)

```
SELECT ID, concat(transcription,' ',COUNT(*),' Times')
FROM
(
    SELECT ID,SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( Description, ' ', l10.n * 10 + l1.n + 1), ' ', -1) AS transcription
    FROM Product
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 0
    ) l1
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 0
    ) l10
    WHERE LENGTH(Description) - LENGTH( REPLACE( Description, ' ', '')) >= l10.n * 10 + l1.n
)A
GROUP BY ID, transcription;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a `COUNT` on the text.

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(Description) AS Times
FROM TableName
GROUP BY ID
```